# iphone attachment size of an image

Tags: iphone, image, email, size, attachment

In my applications, I am attaching a 3000 x 3000 (px) image rougly 3.0 MB.
I usually get an error in logs:
": Could not write any more data to the consumer"

Also, I get memory warning and sometimes the app crashes, though i am releasing as much memory as possible if there's a warning.

So I just want to know that what does ": Could not write any more data to the consumer" means.

I have googled it, but I couldn't find anything related.

Comment: Guess: 3000x3000 is too big for an image in the iphone?? But 3MB of data should not make your app crash, nor even get warnings of low memory. I presume you have other memory leaks that are making your app crash. Have you tried instruments? (leaks)

Comment: 3000x3000 pixel image (at 32bits/pixel) is something like 36MB.  It's only 3MB compressed to disk...

Comment: agree with Stephen! I solved problem by resizing them. But still don't know what the particular warning means. Cheers!

Comment: I have the same message in my logfiles. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageDestination/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageDestinationFinalize  "Writes image data and properties to the data, URL, or data consumer associated with the image destination.", indicates that metadata cannot be written. I have not  verified this though.

Comment: I get this same warning on a 1536 x 2048 image attached.